# drawableBottom does not work

Tags: java, android

I can not understand why my code does not work for 30 minutes.
MainActivity.java:

```
package app.test;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

It is main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:autoLink="email|web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the main code bottom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <size
        android:height="1dp"
        android:width="70dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />

</shape>
```

Also I attach a screenshot on which everything is clearly visible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOHkM.jpg

Comment: just for testing try `android:drawableBottom="@drawable/some_png_file"`

Comment: Just for testing in codebottom.xml   trye  <solid android:color="@android:color/red" />..Your trying back screen backroung text view drwable bottom in black color ...So change text color

Comment: I see that you're trying to display a black line below the text over a black background, try with a white background or a white line.

Comment: Ok I checked and it works. But why does not my method work?

Comment: so you want 70x1 dp black rectangle at the bottom?

Comment: The fact is that I have this error: bottom.xml:9: error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'color' with value '@android:color/red').

Comment: The whole problem is solved by this code android:color="@android:color/white", thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shape is black as your background layout, you will never see it.

It's a good approach you change your backgrounds elements color (even just to see the elements size) to align your layout with your expectations